# Different DataAnnotation attributes for derived classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I develop ASP.NET MVC4 app, EF Code first.
I have base class:

```
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

And i have some derived classes, for example:

```
public class City : Entity
{
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

And many other derived classes (Article, Topic, Car etc). Now i want to implement "Required" attribute to Title property in all classes and i want there are different ErrorMessages for different derived classes. For example, "Title must not be empty" for Topic class, "Please name your car" for Car class etc. How can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could make the property virtual in the base class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then override it in the child class, make it required and specify the error message that you would like to be displayed:

```
public class City : Entity
{
    public int Population { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please name your city")]
    public override string Title
    {
        get { return base.Title; }
        set { base.Title = value; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use [`FluentValidation.NET`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead of data annotations to define your validation logic and in this case you could have different validators for the different concrete types. For example:

```
public class CityValidator: AbstractValidator<City>
{
    public CityValidator()
    {
        this
            .RuleFor(x => x.Title)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Please name your city");
    }
}

public class CarValidator: AbstractValidator<Car>
{
    public CityValidator()
    {
        this
            .RuleFor(x => x.Title)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("You should specify a name for your car");
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Virtual/override option is good for my application. This is what i need. Thanks!

Comment: When you define a property in the base class, it should be used by ALL derived classes.

Comment: By making the property virtual in base class, Range validator is hitting declared in child class.